# border-radius не работает в слайдере Swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

```
<div class="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide items1"><img src ="./img/work-metiew-smith.jpg"></div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide items1"><img src="./img/work-alex-nowak.jpg"></div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide items1"><img src="./img/work-victory.jpg"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
              </div>
```

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
      background-color: #0c0c0c;

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;

      border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```
let swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 600,
    loop: true,
    effect: 'fade',
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  });
```

Почему не работает border-radius?[image: изображения должны быть круглыми]

Comment: Возможно левый и правый край картинки скрыты под черным фоном?
Углы скругляются, но Вы этого не видите под ним.
Попробуйте немного уменьшить % скругления и посмотрите поведение картинки.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно применить `border-radius: 50%;` не к контейнеру картинки, а к самой картинке.

```
.swiper-slide img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```